# Convert Excel spreadsheets data to LATEX graphic

Tags: graphics, vector, charts, excel

Does anybody know a xla to Convert Excel data to a LATEX native graphic?
For tables we can use this module
https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/excel2latex?lang=en

I know you can save as a picture but I would like to have a vector graphic.

Comment: You should be able you print those to file, for example PDF files. And then include those in latex. But then again depending on what the data is and how it is arranged, having LaTeX format it might look better.

Comment: Save your excel data in a csv file. Then, pgfplots will do the rest.